# Visual Studio Intellisense only works partially

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a project that builds successfully. 
But when i try to navigate to some of the definitions I get this error:

[image: Can not navigate to the symbol under the caret]

and also the colors are white on some classes:

[image]

the version is Vs2019 rc. i didn't have this problem with 2019 preview.